# R Studio Server cannot be embedded in the iFrame framework

Tags: r, iframe, rstudio-server, obsidian

#### Describe the problem in detail

I tried to embed R Studio Server in Obsidian software to complete my R-Obsidian workflow.
From the [official RStudio manual](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/1.2.981-2/tutorial-api.html#tutorial-api) I found that R Studio disables this embedding by default for security reasons, but it can be set with the parameter `www-frame-origin`. I configured it according to the official R Studio manual but still could not embed it in files like Obsidian or Rmarkdown.

#### System details

```
RStudio Edition: R studio server
RStudio Version :  2022.07.1+554
OS Version: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 
R Version: 4.2.1
```

#### Steps to reproduce the problem

- Add `www-frame-origin=59.66.XX.X(my IP address)` to /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf
- Use `<iframe id="rstudio" src="http://103.238.XXX.XX:8787/"></iframe>` in obsidian or rmd to embed R Studio Server in the iFrame
- Tried to log in, got "Error: Temporary server error, please try again" error

[image: Screen Shot 2022-10-21 at 4 53 14 PM]